# How to use table variable with other parameter in SQL?

Tags: sql, variables, exec

```
  DECLARE @country varchar(30) = 'UK'
  DECLARE @table varchar(50)
  SET @table = 'NORTHWND.dbo.Employees'
  EXEC('select e.LastName, e.FirstName, e.PostalCode
  from ' + @table +' as e
  where e.Country like '+ @country )
```

Gives:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
Invalid column name 'UK'.

But I want to list all 'UK' Employees.  Do I need to add parenthesis and how would I do that?

Comment: This is a poor example.  You don't need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Your query results in `where e.Country like UK` but it should be `where e.Country like 'UK'`

Comment: there should be somethink like `EXEC('select e.LastName, e.FirstName, e.PostalCode from ' + @table +' as e  where e.Country like '''+ @country+ '''' )`

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the ' ' around UK in your where clause, try this:

```
DECLARE @country varchar(30) = 'UK'
  DECLARE @table varchar(50)
  SET @table = 'NORTHWND.dbo.Employees'
  EXEC('select e.LastName, e.FirstName, e.PostalCode
  from ' + @table +' as e
  where e.Country like '''+ @country +'''' )
```

Comment: dbajtr - Wow you make it look so easy, thank you very much indeed